# Finding $C_n=-C_{n-1}+C_{n-2}$

Tags: closed-form

$$\begin{cases}
C_n=-C_{n-1}+C_{n-2}\\
C_0=1\\
C_1=0
\end{cases} $$

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
C_n \\
C_{n-1} 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
-1 && 1 \\
1 && 0
\end{pmatrix}^n
\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{vmatrix} 
\lambda+1 && -1 \\
-1 && \lambda
\end{vmatrix}=\lambda^2+\lambda-1$ So $\lambda_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{ \sqrt{5}}{2}$

$$C_n=a(-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{ \sqrt{5}}{2})^nC_{n-1}+b(\frac{1}{2}- \frac{ \sqrt{5}}{2})^nC_{n-2}$$

$$\begin{cases}
1=a+b\\
0=a(-\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{ \sqrt{5}}{2})+b(\frac{1}{2}- \frac{ \sqrt{5}}{2})
\end{cases}$$

$C_n=\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}- \frac{ \sqrt{5}}{2})^n$

Is it correct?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: You made a slight sign error in your C_n formula. The second base is (-1/2-sqrt(5)/2). You had $1/2$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from an offset (shift of n to n-1) this is https://oeis.org/A039834 in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which provides an equivalent formula.